# Find The Sum Of Number

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Find the sum of all the numbers *greater* than $10000$ formed with the digits $0,2,4,6,8$ No digit being repeated.

Comment: greater or under?

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: There are 96 such numbers (5! * 4/5 since initial 0 is impossible), so you could just list them and add them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the sum for all numbers and then substract those that are smaller than $10,000$.

To find the sum for all of them notice that if you pick a digit and a specific position then there are $4!$ words that have that digit in that position. Therefore the digit $d$ contributes $d\times 4! \times (1+10+100+1000+10000)$ to the sum.

Therefore, you want $4!\times 11,111\times (0+2+4+6+8)=24\times 11,111\times 20=5333280$

We can use the same exact method to calculate the sum for number under $10000$. You get $3!\times 1,111\times (2+4+6+8)=6\times 11,111\times 20=133320$

So the final answer is $5333280-133320=5199960$